# Problem with using label to show up before code executes

Tags: python, function, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def function1():
    L=Label(root,text="Loading...").pack()
    for i in range(10000):
        L1=Label(root,text=str(i**2)).pack()
function1()
```

This is a simplified version of my code.
How to get the function to display the label as "Loading..." calculate the values for a few seconds then at last show up the labels?
Usually the program waits till the whole code is done and shows loading.

Comment: I think you can use `update_idletasks()`

Comment: You will create 10001 labels.  Is it what you want? Or do you just want one label to show all the results one by one?

Comment: 10,000 labels is awfully excessive.

Comment: Try adding a `root.update_idletasks()` after the `L=Label(root,text="Loading...").pack()` statement — which is going to assign `None` to `L` btw, because that's the value `pack()` always returns.